# Non-homogenous differential equation guessing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So we have a non-homogeneous differential equation

$$ y''' - y' = 4te^{-t} $$

and has a fundamental characteristic solution set:
$$ (1, e^t, e^{-t}) $$

So initially my guess for $ y_p $ would be $ y_p = Ate^{-t} $ Adding a term t there because $ e^{-t} $ is a part of the homogeneous solution.'

But this turns out to be incorrect because the solution manual want me to use the guess $ (At^2 +Bt)e^{-t} $

And so my question is, by what logic should i use to come to that conclusion my self?
after that the solution is quite easy.

Answer (score 3):

If the right side is a sum of terms $p(t)e^{rt}$, $r$ real or complex, $p$ a polynomial, and if $m$ is the multiplicity of $r$ in the characteristic polynomial of the left side, then the trial solution for each one of the right side terms is $t^mq(t)e^{rt}$, where $\deg q=\deg p$ and the coefficients of $q$ are the unknown variables. The complete particular solution is the sum of all these terms.

Here you have $r=-1$, $\deg(p)=1$ and $m=1$, so that
$$
y_p=t(At+B)e^{-t}
$$

---

Note that trig. terms like $te^t\cos(t)$ are two terms with roots/exponents $r=1±i$, so that in the trial solution you get also 2 terms (in this case with a total of 4 coefficients). You can then combine them again to real-valued functions as $(A_0t+B_0)e^t\cos(t)+(A_1t+B_1)e^t\sin(t)$. In general you will not get "pure" terms in the particular solution, even if the right side only has a single sine or cosine term.

Comment: Lutz there is an additional t it seems to me ( $B$ not $Bt$)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i didn't quite follow that. This is very unlike how we are taught. Also I don't understand how that argument works.

We are using:
Elementary Differential
Equations and Boundary
Value Problems

10th edition
William E. Boyce
Richard C. DiPrima

Comment: @Isham : Thank you, this was a copy-paste error from a problem where deg p=3

Comment: @Corvo : That is the kernel of that method. You need to identify these parts of the right side and construct the trial solution accordingly. If the right side can not be decomposed in this fashion, then this method does not work and you need to apply the more general variation-of-constants. Note that trig. terms like $te^t\cos(t)$ are two terms with roots/exponents $r=1\pm i$, and in the trial you can assemble them again to real-valued functions $(A_0t+B_0)e^t\cos(t)+(A_1t+B_1)e^t\sin(t)$.